# Designated Representative - HOA

Tags: contract-law, power-of-attorney, hoa

In reference to this statue, https://www.azleg.gov/ars/33/01804.htm

> ...or any person designated by a member in writing as the member's representative and all members or designated representatives so desiring shall be permitted to attend and speak...

What document might the association require to see a non-lawyer is representating a member of their association? Would a durable special power of attorney work?

Does that still work as a company representing the homeowner? Should a simple statement suffice instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An email would be enough. As would an SMS.

“Designated in writing” is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, Dale, I thought as much. Appreciate the response.